# Insert into and select combination is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is my query which I want to insert the value which should be selected from another table:

```
insert into payment_details_kohin(installment_no)
 values(
select count(installment_amount)+2  
from kohin_plan.payment_details_insert 
where customer_id='KBP100058'
)
```

…but its gives me an error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'customer_id', table
>   'kohinoor_rdfd.kohin_plan.payment_details_kohin'; column does not
>   allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

When I try the following query:

```
insert into payment_details_kohin(installment_no)
values(
select count(installment_amount)+2  
from kohin_plan.payment_details_insert 
where customer_id='KBP100058'
)
```

…it gives me the following error

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Comment: dear friend check my post it will work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a non-NULL customer id.  You need to insert it into the table as well:

```
insert into payment_details_kohin(customer_id, installment_no)
    select customer_id, count(installment_amount)+2  
    from kohin_plan.payment_details_insert 
    where customer_id='KBP100058';
```

However, when I see such `inserts`, sometimes what is really wanted is an update:

```
update payment_details_kohin
    set installment_no = (select count(installment_amount) + 2
                          from kohin_plan.payment_details_insert 
                          where payment_details_kohin.customer_id = payment_details_insert.customer_id
                         )
    where customer_id = 'KBP100058';
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need the Values clause here just do as follows

```
INSERT INTO payment_details_kohin(installment_no)
SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(installment_amount), 0) + 2  
FROM kohin_plan.payment_details_insert 
WHERE customer_id = 'KBP100058'
```

Answer (score 1):

Dear Friend when you are inserting value in one table from another table or using select for inseting then you dont have to spacity the "Value" Key Word

so simple do the following

```
INSERT INTO payment_details_kohin(installment_no)
SELECT count(installment_amount) + 2  
FROM kohin_plan.payment_details_insert 
WHERE customer_id = 'KBP100058'
```